# Vue.js - Define path of vue route based on URL query params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

Let's assume I have this URL
`http://localhost:8080/public/form?code=fhuZ15aHy`

I have defined a route in my `route.js` file like this

```
{ 
  path: '/public/form?code=:code',
  name: 'survey',
  component: () => import('./views/form')
}
```

which is supposed to reuse the same component based on the `code` query parameter coming from URL.

In my `form.vue` component I have defined a prop like this:

```
props: {
   code: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   }
}
```

But this is not working, in the sense that I am not redirected to any page.

I think I'm doing wrong with how I defined the path of the route. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not define the query within the path

You should write like this:

```
{ 
  path: '/public/form',
  name: 'survey',
  component: () => import('./views/form')
}
```

```
router.push({ path: '/public/form', query: { code } })
```

And within the component you can access the query like this

```
const {code} = this.$route.query
```

Comment: where should I put the ```router.push()```? inside the ```index.js``` file?

Comment: No . It's a way of programmatic navigation,  Look here -https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html. 
But of course you can navigate manually
It is recommended that you see the documentation of the vue router - it is very clear.